# Compare streams

Tags: stream, lisp, common-lisp

I need to check if a given stream is a terminal stream. For example, with `*standard-output*` I do `(equal (synonym-stream-symbol *standard-output*) *terminal-io*)`, but it returns nil.
This is strange because `(synonym-stream-symbol *standard-output*)` returns `*terminal-io*`.
Any ideas? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 8):

The reason is that `synonym-stream-symbol` ([manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_syn_st.htm#synonym-stream-symbol)) returns a symbol, while evaluating `*terminal-io*` returns the stream associated to the global var.

You can check which is the right symbol simply quoting the name of the stream:

```
CL-USER> (eq (synonym-stream-symbol *standard-output*) '*terminal-io*)
T
```